Accessing a column from a crosstalk::shareddata object that has been filtered by a crosstalk::filter_select
I can't figure out how to retrieve a column from a shareddata object that has been filtered by a filter_select.  The attached code runs, but does not respond to the filtering... I am guessing that shared_data$data(withFilter = TRUE) is returning the original dataframe, not the filtered dataframe? How do you get the filtered version?
---
title: "Dull dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

make_plot <- function(tbbl, label){
  ggplot(tbbl, aes(wt, mpg, label=label))+
    geom_text()
}

nested <- mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  nest() |>
  mutate(plot=map2(data, cyl, make_plot)) |>
  select(-data)

shared_data <- SharedData$new(nested)
```

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
-----------------------------------------------

```{r}
crosstalk::filter_select(
  "fltr", 
  " Select # of cylinders",
  shared_data, 
  ~cyl, 
  multiple = FALSE,
  selected = "6"
)
```

Column {data-width=700}
---------------------------------------------

### Plot

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
filtered_data <- shared_data$data(withFilter = TRUE)
plt <- filtered_data$plot[[1]]
ggplotly(plt)
```

Created on 2024-08-14 with reprex v2.1.0
